# Puking blood: how to make a scrapy, python, and postrgres ecosystem inside Windows 7 that can deal with unicode

Tags: python, windows, unicode, windows-7

Would *really* appreciate if anyone can help me either fix the problems I describe below, or (worst case) suggest an alternative environment that would work (although I'm loathe to upgrade to Windows 10)

---

I am scraping mostly-english webpages from a Japanese website. A few required fields have kanji in them.

I'm using scrapy, postgres 9.5, and python 2.7 on a Windows 7 installation.

Scrapy has to run in a cmd.exe shell, and I'm examining the database results in a psql.exe instance also running in a cmd.exe shell.  I've been using Console2 application for the cmd.exe.

It's a horrible experience to debug in this setup:

**scrapy shell**

I'm unable to do any diagnostic `print()` messages because the kanji causes an Exception

```
>  print st['kanji_name']   
> File "C:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
> position 0-8: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've seen solutions about changing the active code page to with `chcp 65001` but scrapy doesn't understand cp65001 apparently

```
C:\Users\_python\j_school>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

Throws the error:

```
C:\Users\_python\j_school>scrapy crawl j_school

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\_python\j_school\j_school\spiders\j_school_spider.py", line 141, in parse
    print(st['english_name'])
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
```

**PSQL**

PSQL already warns me on startup

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin>psql m_experiment postgres
psql (9.5rc1)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
```

regardless of whether I try the `chcp 65001`, psql still will not print these.

```
m_experiment=# select * from schools limit 1;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe6 0x9d 0xb1 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

I've also tried to set the client_encoding, but this then blows up something and postgres insists I'm out of memory!

```
m_experiment=# SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET
m_experiment=# show client_encoding;
Not enough memory.
m_experiment=#
```

I discovered multiple bug reports about this issue circa 2011 but it was never fixed???  Anyway, I [found a manual way to fix it](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/08/18/windows-psql-and-utf8-client_encoding-issues/),  `pset pager off` incantation solves the issue.

Now psql can at least spit out a response, although it doesn't render the kanji correctly.

```
m_experiment=# select english_name, kanji_name from schools limit 1;
            english_name             |     kanji_name
-------------------------------------+--------------------
 TOKYO INTERNATIONAL JAPANESE SCHOOL | Ã¦ÂÂ±Ã¤ÂºÂ¬Ã¥â€ºÂ½Ã©Å¡â€ºÃ¦â€”Â¥Ã¦Å“Â¬Ã¨ÂªÅ¾Ã¥Â­Â¦Ã©â„¢Â¢
(1 row)
```

---

One hack-solution was to change my locale to Japanese.  Now the console shows my kanji properly.  But it screws up the display thereafter (the >prompt shows up strangely and the cursor graphic doesn't align to where the cursor actually is!).

[image]

Comment: I'm loath to suggest it, but seeing that you're using linuxy tools, have you considered doing this in Linux?  Perhaps in a VM?

Comment: Either that or Cygwin (I would just go Linux tho, you'll never regret it)

Comment: @evan058: I'm not sure whether Cygwin would help, and it's such a monstrosity I'd save it for a last resort.  Is there actually a Cygwin version of Python to begin with?

Comment: Yep, Cygwin has its own Python along with a lot of other ported tools

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yah, this may make most sense long-term.  Do you have any recommendations for which distribution to use?  I'm principally doing python/postrgresql/scrapy sort-of-stuff.

Comment: @user3556757 Ubuntu is a good start. Large community and fairly user friendly.

Comment: Python 3 will be much easier to debug than Python 2, because it will usually catch logic errors like trying to concatenate text and bytes together. Printing is a separate question (especially on Windows) which has already been answered elsewhere on SO.

Comment: @roeland yeah, but I think the issue w/ Python 3 is that   Scrapy on Python 3 on Windows doesn't work (yet) because parts of Twisted library don't work on Python3+Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, `cp437` is the US Windows console default encoding.  You could try temporarily switching your system locale to "Japanese(Japan)" so you could print Kanji to the console.  Go to Control Panel, Region and Language, Administrative tab and click "Change system locale...".  After rebooting, the default Windows console default encoding should be one suitable for Japanese.

I've done this before to print Chinese to the console.  The setting only affects non-Unicode programs, and most programs are fully Unicode nowadays.

Comment: yah, rough solution but it mostly works.  Though displaying kanji in psql seems to subsequently make the command prompt and cursor squirrely (added an image of it in my original post)

Comment: @user3556757 Try the original console instead of Console2. It probably has to do with kanji using full width characters and maybe the original console handles it better. Maybe.